# HTML Table Grid

Tags: php, html, sql, grid, html-table

Need some help.
I'm creating a table view with grid/borders.
However,some borders can't be seen although I'm including in tags the style=''.
Much better if I will tell that I only see the table border which is included in table tag.

Please see attached file for the format.

[image]

By the way I'm getting the records in database via PHP script.
Here is my code:

```
$result.="<br/><br/><br/>
        <table style='border:solid 1px;'>";
$result.="<thead style='border-bottom:thin solid'><th style='text-    align:center;border-style:solid 1px'>YC ".$store_name."</th></thead>
            <tr><td></td>
            <td colspan='3'>Service Time   </td>
        <td colspan='3'>Production Time</td>
        <!--<td colspan='3'>Customer Feedback</td>
        <td colspan='3'>Customer Feedback</td>
        <td colspan='3'>Customer Feedback</td>-->
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>TC Within<br>30 mins.</td>
        <td>Total<br>TC</td>
        <td><br/>%</td>
        <td>Within 15 <br/>mins.</td>
        <td>Total <br/>TC</td>
        <td><br/>%</td>

        </tr>
        <tr></tr>";
//get PartView
$query = "SELECT * FROM Part_view WHERE StoreID = ".$store_id." AND datepart(month,TransDate) = '".$month."' AND datepart(year,TransDate) = '".$year."' ORDER BY TransDate ASC ";
 $que = mssql_query($query);
    while($row=mssql_fetch_array($que)){
        $transdate =date('d',strtotime($row['TransDate']));
        $tc30 = $row['TC30'];
        $totaltc30 = $row['Total_TRX1'];
        $hitrate = round($row['Hitrate']);
        $pd15 = $row['PDT15'];
        $totalpd15 = $row['Total_TRX2'];
        $production = round($row['ProdTime']);
        $excellence = $row['Excellence'];
        $totalexcellence = $row['Total_TRX4'];
        $excellencepercent = round($row['ExcelPercent']);
        $good = $row['Good'];
        $totalgood = $row['Total_TRX5'];
        $goodpercent = round($row['GoodPercent']);
        $poor = $row['Poor'];
        $totalpoor = $row['Total_TRX6'];
        $poorpercent = round($row['PoorPercent']);
        if($hitrate==""){
            $hitrates = "";
        }else{
            $hitrates = $hitrate;
        }
            $result.="<tr>
                     <td>".$transdate."</td>
                     <td>".$tc30."</td>
                    <td>".$totaltc30."</td>
                    <td>".$hitrate."%&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                     <td>".$pd15."</td>
                    <td>".$totalpd15."</td>
                    <td>".$production."%&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

        </tr>";
    }
    $result.="</table>";
    echo $result;
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: you should share the html and css in your question

Comment: We need to see your code

Comment: Could help if you told us which borders you can't see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think what you are actually asking is why the entire grid isn't being 'bordered'. You can use CSS to accomplish this far cleaner than inline styles. You need to set styles for TD.

Code:

```
    
    table {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-collapse: separate;
    background-color: white;
    }
    table th {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    background-color: white;
    }
    table td {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    background-color: white;
    }
```

If you use this in your CSS you can remove all the inline styling you have already, this code will fix it all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool to create the table. But I recommend you to do that by yourself. And you should include your code and we can help you to fix that.

Tool: http://divtable.com/generator/